# Extract values in certain numerical range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column "AP" where every cell contains values like this

```
5358  161043   22344   8444   103145  69221044
```

"5358 161043 22344 8444 103145 69221044 " are all one cell, AP2 in this case. I know it's a mess, but I inherited it from somebody else and am trying to clean it up.

I need some way to extract those values in the numerical range between 6623 and 12756. I could do with either a search and replace command that deletes all values outside of this range or a function that copies the values in question to another column.

Answer (score 2):

I made up some dummy data and put it in Column A on my sheet. In Column B, I used the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=$L$35,A1<=$L$36),"Yes","No")
```

This is a simple filter that returns "Yes" for values in your target range (I dropped them in cells L35 and L36).

[image]

Next, select those two columns and turn on the Filter.

[image]

Now, on the Home Tab, go to the Editing ribbon and choose "Find & Select". Pick the option that says "Go To Special..."

Select the option called Visible Cells Only and press OK.

Press Copy or use CTRL-C. This should select only the rows with the data you want.

Now, if you paste in a blank sheet, you'll paste only the data corresponding to your desired date range. Note: In my example, I didn't leave Row 1 blank for headers, so when I applied my filter, I ended up with one "No" left over. You can either delete the straggler, or just leave a blank row on top at the beginning so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am afraid I didn't clearly communicate what the cell looks like: "5358  161043   22344   8444   103145  69221044 " are all one cell, AP2 in my case. I know it's a mess, but I inherited it from somebody else and am trying to clean it up. So the function you so kindly provided only tells me if the desired value is in there, which is the case for almost all of these.

Comment: Based on this information, I suggest you either edit your question or start a new one altogether, as you're now asking for something completely different. I believe you may want to use the Text to Columns functionality to separate your data into separate cells before attempting to filter it.

Answer (score 0):

First enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function GrabData(r As Range) As String
    Dim cel As Range, v As String, a, d As Double

    GrabData = ""

    For Each cel In r
        v = cel.Text
        arr = Split(v, " ")
            For Each a In arr
                If IsNumeric(a) Then
                    d = CDbl(a)
                    If d > 6622 And d < 12757 Then GrabData = GrabData & " " & a
                End If
            Next a
        Next cel
End Function
```

Then if you have data in **AP1** through **AP3**, pick another cell and enter:

```
=GrabData(AP1:AP3)
```

For example:

[image]

As you see, the values are returned in a **space separated** string, just like the inputs.